# <svg> element match child width and height

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a simple svg element which has children of  elements: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9wd7nwpt/1/)

```
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g opacity="1" transform="translate(0,0) scale(3,3) rotate(0)">
        ...
    </g>
</svg>
```

The first `<g>` node has a size of about 31x42 px, but the `<svg>` element has the default size of 300x150 px. I want the svg to take the size of its children nodes, how would I do that? Adding `height=100%` doesn't work (it remains at 300x150).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind to use javascript you can do this:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].style.height = document.getElementsByTagName('g')[0].getBoundingClientRect().height + 'px';
```

```html
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g opacity="1" transform="translate(0,0) scale(3,3) rotate(0)">
        <g transform="translate(2.2775,3) scale(1,1) rotate(0)">
            <g transform="translate(0,0) scale(1,1) rotate(0)">
                <rect x="-1.2" y="-3.5999999999999996" width="5.430000000000001" height="7.469999999999999" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)" stroke="none"></rect>
                <g transform="translate(0,0) scale(0.3,0.3) rotate(0)">
                    <path stroke="none" d="M8.05,-8L8.05,5.1Q8.05,6.3 8.4,6.95Q8.75,7.6 10.1,7.65L10.1,8.9L1.65,8.9L1.65,7.65Q3,7.6 3.35,6.95Q3.7,6.3 3.7,5.1L3.7,-3.35L3.65,-3.35L1,1L0,0.6L3.65,-8L8.05,-8"></path>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(4.029999999999999,0) scale(1,1) rotate(0)">
                <rect x="-1.2" y="-3.5999999999999996" width="6.48" height="7.6499999999999995" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)" stroke="none"></rect>
                <g transform="translate(0,0) scale(0.3,0.3) rotate(0)">
                    <path stroke="none" d="M4.65,-4.65Q5.65,-4.25 5.8,-2.75Q5.75,-1.75 4.95,-1.1Q4.15,-0.4 3.15,-0.4Q0.7,-0.65 0.45,-3Q0.45,-4.95 2.05,-6.45Q3.65,-7.9 7.45,-8Q10.35,-7.9 11.8,-6.4Q13.3,-4.95 13.3,-3.05Q12.95,0.15 9.85,1.3Q6.8,2.4 4.55,3.95L4.55,4Q8.05,3.6 10.1,5.05L11.5,5.15Q12.25,4.85 12.35,3.15L13.6,3.15Q13.65,5.3 12.85,7.3Q12,9.35 9.45,9.5Q7.65,9.3 6.5,8.25Q5.35,7.1 3.8,6.8Q1.7,6.9 1.4,8.9L0.1,8.9Q-0.35,6.15 1.7,4.45Q3.75,2.75 5.85,1.65Q7.15,0.85 8.05,-0.4Q9,-1.7 9.05,-3.3Q8.95,-6.85 6.15,-6.6Q3.45,-6.55 3.55,-5.55Q3.7,-5 4.65,-4.65"></path>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(4.3675,9) scale(1,1) rotate(0)">
            <g transform="translate(0,0) scale(1,1) rotate(0)">
                <rect x="-1.2" y="-3.5999999999999996" width="6.33" height="7.6499999999999995" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)" stroke="none"></rect>
                <g transform="translate(0,0) scale(0.3,0.3) rotate(0)">
                    <path stroke="none" d="M6.55,-8Q8.45,-8.05 10.4,-7.2Q12.45,-6.4 12.6,-4.15Q12.35,-1.5 10.05,-0.15Q13.15,1.65 13.1,4Q13.05,6.1 11.1,7.75Q9.2,9.4 6.05,9.5Q3.85,9.5 2,8.35Q0.15,7.15 0,4.8Q0.05,3.4 1,2.35Q1.95,1.3 3.2,0.75Q0.55,-0.5 0.35,-3.45Q0.45,-5.8 2.45,-6.9Q4.45,-8 6.55,-8M8.35,-1.05Q9.85,-2.15 10.15,-4.05Q10.15,-5.55 8.8,-6.15Q7.5,-6.8 6.25,-6.75Q4.1,-6.85 3.55,-4.85Q3.75,-3.5 5.7,-2.3Q7.75,-1.1 8.35,-1.05M7.6,3.15L4.7,1.55Q2.8,2.65 2.5,4.75Q2.55,6.1 3.65,7.1Q4.7,8.05 6,8.1Q7.25,8.3 8.35,7.6Q9.4,6.9 9.5,5.55Q9.3,4.05 7.6,3.15"></path>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not really how SVGs are supposed to work.  SVG is an image format.  You normally specify the size of the "canvas" and then you draw things onto it.

It's a bit like saying "There is a cat in this JPEG, how do I set the JPEG to the size of the cat".

That being said, if you don't mind using some JS, Almis' solution will work most of the time.

But otherwise, there is no way to automatically set an SVG to the size of its contents.